# Multiplying (nesting) two big Os

Tags: time-complexity

If a function A calls n^c functions B that runs in O(n^2) time, what is the time complexity of function A? Is it just polynomial (n^c) as well as c has just gotten bigger?

Comment: This is not adding, this is multiplying.

Comment: Actually, the answer depends on whether the inputs to B have the same size n, which everyone seems to assume right now. For an extreme case, if B were always called on inputs of constant size, the resulting time would be O(n^c).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a function *A* calls another function *B*, the total complexity is the product of the complexities of *A* and *B*. So in this case the total complexity is O(*n*<sup>*c*</sup> · *n*<sup>2</sup>) = O(*n*<sup>*c* + 2</sup>).

The general [rules for products](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Product):

> ƒ<sub>1</sub> ∈ O(*g*<sub>1</sub>) and ƒ<sub>2</sub> ∈ O(*g*<sub>2</sub>) ⟹ ƒ<sub>1</sub>·ƒ<sub>2</sub> ∈ O(*g*<sub>1</sub>·*g*<sub>1</sub>)
>
> ƒ·O(*g*) ∈ O(ƒ·*g*)

Comment: i knew I should have added as an answer!

Comment: And that would be O(n^c) but just with a slightly larger `c` :-)